# How to not change published url of script implementation after every change in code

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

is there any solution to not change the url during each implementation?
I created my own form that inserts data from users into a google worksheet.
I need the final code to work for more people, and every time I make some changes to the code, I'll have to send them a new URL.
It would be even better if I could place this application script application in my own domain.

Is there a solution? Thanks for advice

Answer (score 2):

- Select "Manage Deployments"
- Find the active deployment with the URL you would like to keep
- Edit deployment and update version to "New Version"
- Select "Deploy" button

Comment: Thanks, that  helps. Anyway, is there a way how to put script on my own domain?